# jQuery UI tabs enable keyboard control automatically

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs, keyboard

Currently the jQuery UI tabs container has keyboard control to switch between tabs with the left and right keys, but it's only enabled once a tab has been clicked. Is there a way to explicitly enable and disable keyboard control for the widget at will?

Comment: If you start playing with default focus behaviour then you're effectively breaking your site/app for anyone that understands and uses it.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but this is for a simple app that will be used by a smart TV like device with only a d-pad for navigation, so it will be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could by focussing the tab-container at startup i believe

```
$("#myTabContainer").focus();

// or if you need to have focus on a tab

$("#myFirstTab").focus();
```

But do not reset the focus over and over again, otherwise the user couldn't enter any textfield or click-scroll the website